# How to close a window opened in Outlook for Windows from a Outlook web add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I am developing a web add-in and I open the Azure AD authentication window in a popup. However, I need to close this popup as soon as authentication is done. I am redirecting the user to another page where I have placed the javascript code to close the window. The code works fine in Chrome on Windows, Mac, also Outlook on Mac. However the code does not work on Outlook for Windows.

Is there any solution in javascript to close the browser window for any browser version and platform?

Comment: our recommendation would be to use the displayDialog API to complete the authentication flow. Have you considered this? If so, is there a specific reason why this solution won't work for your scenario?

Comment: It worked for me. I redirected the Azure AD login page to my MVC View after authentication and then used Office.context.ui.messageParent(json); on that view to send message to the parent to close the popup dialog.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid trouble with authentication across different browsers use the displayDialog API to complete the authentication workflow. This will allow you to close the dialog once the authentication is completed.